# Wifi device not ready, but it isn't hard nor soft blocked

Tags: wireless, networking

I'm unable to connect to wifi on my Toshiba Satellite U200, even though the wireless card doesn't seem to be blocked:

```
$ rfkill list
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
6: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Note: when I boot it *is* blocked, but doing:

```
modprobe -rfv iwl3945
rfkill unblock all
modprobe -v iwl3945
```

Unblocks it. The led doesn't get turned on. Using the hardware keys doesn't change anything.

The output of `lshw` is:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:18:de:7d:ac:f4
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:42 memory:ffcff000-ffcfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: PRO/100 VE Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 8
       bus info: pci@0000:03:08.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:15:b7:43:1c:56
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e100 driverversion=3.5.24-k2-NAPI duplex=full ip=158.110.95.216 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=56 mingnt=8 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:20 memory:ffaff000-ffafffff ioport:bf40(size=64)
```

And here are various information I collected:

```
##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux pellicano 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1041]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
03:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection [8086:1092] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0001]
    Kernel driver in use: e100

##### lsusb #####

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c045 Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 STMicroelectronics Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

PRODID_1=""
PRODID_2=""
PRODID_3=""
PRODID_4=""
MANFID=0000,0000
FUNCID=255

##### rfkill #####

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
6: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #####

Tabella di routing IP del kernel
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         158.110.95.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
158.110.95.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwl3945
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

- Device: eth0  [Connessione via cavo 1] ---------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e100
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         158.110.95.216
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         158.110.95.1

    DNS:             158.110.104.32
    DNS:             158.110.1.7

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz

##### lsmod #####

iwl3945                63619  0 
iwlegacy               88016  1 iwl3945
mac80211              545990  2 iwl3945,iwlegacy
cfg80211              409394  3 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwl3945.ko
firmware:       iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:s
description:    Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux
srcversion:     C93C31FCEBBAE1F376E495F
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004227sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004222sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004227sv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004222sv*sd00001044bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004222sv*sd00001034bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004222sv*sd00001005bc*sc*i*
depends:        iwlegacy,cfg80211,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:96:DC:92:B0:1D:75:9D:3E:85:62:EA:32:A1:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           antenna:select antenna (1=Main, 2=Aux, default 0 [both]) (int)
parm:           swcrypto:using software crypto (default 1 [software]) (int)
parm:           disable_hw_scan:disable hardware scanning (default 1) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwlegacy.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    iwl-legacy: common functions for 3945 and 4965
srcversion:     400F302BE5C25B3C98A6CE8
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:96:DC:92:B0:1D:75:9D:3E:85:62:EA:32:A1:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking (int)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bluetooth co-exist (bool)

##### modules #####

lp

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist wmi

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x8086:0x1092 (e100)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x4222 (iwl3945)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[ 1336.469707] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Radio disabled by HW RF Kill switch
[ 1336.470773] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Radio disabled by HW RF Kill switch
```

Does anybody know what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it. There was an small hardware switch on the side that was turned off.
This is indicated by the `dmesg`:

```
[ 1336.469707] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Radio disabled by HW RF Kill switch
```

However I have no idea why `rfkill list` says `hard blocked: no`...